# IndentationError: expected an indented block but i dont know why

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a tic tac toe AI and ran into this little problem.

```
def tic_tac_toe_AI(board):
    ...
    if board[5] == '':
        return 5
    ...
```

This appears in a function where board is a dicitionary.
But I get this message and I dont know why:

```
    if board[5] == '':
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Ok so the full code snippet is here:

```
def AI_easy(board, symbol):
    if symbol == 'X':
        computer = 'X'
        player = 'O'
    else:
        computer = 'O'
        player = 'X'

    possible_win_moves = test_win(board, computer)
    if len(possible_win_moves) > 0:
        print(possible_win_moves)
        return random_move(possible_win_moves)


    possible_lose_moves = test_win(board, player)
    if len(possible_lose_moves) > 0:
        return random_move(possible_lose_moves)

    possible_moves = []
    for i in [1,3,7,9]:
        if board[i] == '':
            possible_moves.append(i)
        if i == 9:

    if board[5] == '':
        return 5

    possible_moves = []
    for i in [2,4,6,8]:
        if board[i] == '':
            possible_moves.append(i)
        if i == 8:
            return random_move(possible_moves)
```

And I use an editor were 4 spaces are automatically replaced by one tab. So this is not the problem.

Comment: The problem is somewhere before this `if` statement. Paste the code if you want some help

Comment: Well you have a line `if i == 9:` which has no content after it...

Comment: Please note that you have 3 answers that none of them is related to your problem. Read about [ask] and always make sure to include a [mre]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is the `if i == 9:` 2 lines above where the error says it's from